# Block no referrer downloads

Tags: .htaccess

I'm hosting my files on my server and I want to keep these files from being download by leechers. Also the format link of mine is something similar to: domain.com/download/Name.rar where people can easily guess the name of the file and try downloading by entering links in the browser address bar. I don't want these 2 things to happen and think of using .htaccess to block all no referrer downloads. I've tried some method I can find online:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(rar)$ - [F]
```

But it didn't work at all, I was still able to download files from address bar. Did I do something wrong? Assuming the folder I store my files is /download/store, where do I have to put the .htaccess file? Can anyone give me a full guide on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want to *deny* blank referers. Your condition denies referers that are *not* blank and does not equal your domain. So you need to get rid of this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I removed that line but still able to download from address bar, without referrer.

Comment: EDIT: It DID work for .png image file when I edit the .htaccess file in home directory. But it doesn't work for .rar files